# How to add test coverage to Camunda Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, code-coverage, junit4, camunda

I want to add test coverage to my JUnit tests for my BPMN files. I read [Camunda BPM Process Test Coverage](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-process-test-coverage) and tried the [Spring example](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-process-test-coverage/blob/master/test/src/test/java/org/camunda/bpm/extension/process_test_coverage/spring/SpringProcessWithCoverageTest.java) with the Camunda Spring Boot Starter test configuration, but I get an exception.

**Code:**

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Deployment(resources = {"test.bpmn"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {StandaloneInMemoryTestConfiguration.class})
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProcessEngine processEngine;

    @Rule
    @ClassRule
    public static ProcessEngineRule rule;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initRule() {
        rule = TestCoverageProcessEngineRuleBuilder.create(processEngine).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
16:34:50.858 [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1df82230] to prepare test instance [com.MyTest@58d75e99]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'standaloneInMemoryTestConfiguration': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.test.helper.StandaloneInMemoryTestConfiguration]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.test.helper.StandaloneInMemoryTestConfiguration.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1236)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:107)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.test.helper.StandaloneInMemoryTestConfiguration]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.test.helper.StandaloneInMemoryTestConfiguration.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1228)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.test.helper.StandaloneInMemoryTestConfiguration.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

I also tried to build the process engine manually in the `initRule` method (removing autowired property `processEngine` and class annotation `@ContextConfiguration`):

```java
@PostConstruct
private void initRule() {
    ProcessEngine processEngine = new StandaloneInMemoryTestConfiguration().buildProcessEngine();
    rule = TestCoverageProcessEngineRuleBuilder.create(processEngine).build();
}
```

but I get still an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.history.handler.DbHistoryEventHandler cannot be cast to org.camunda.bpm.extension.process_test_coverage.listeners.FlowNodeHistoryEventHandler
    at org.camunda.bpm.extension.process_test_coverage.junit.rules.TestCoverageProcessEngineRule.initializeListenerRunState(TestCoverageProcessEngineRule.java:259)
    at org.camunda.bpm.extension.process_test_coverage.junit.rules.TestCoverageProcessEngineRule.initializeRunState(TestCoverageProcessEngineRule.java:240)
    at org.camunda.bpm.extension.process_test_coverage.junit.rules.TestCoverageProcessEngineRule.starting(TestCoverageProcessEngineRule.java:134)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher.startingQuietly(TestWatcher.java:108)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher.access$000(TestWatcher.java:46)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:53)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.test.ProcessEngineRule$1.evaluate(ProcessEngineRule.java:165)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it configuring the process coverage project based Historyhandler for the spring boot setup. Based on this [documentation](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/configuration/#defaulthistoryconfiguration) this did the job after adding it to your configuration class:

```
@Bean
public HistoryEventHandler customHistoryEventHandler() {
    return new FlowNodeHistoryEventHandler();
}
```